# Magento checkout page issue

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

I have Magento 1.9.2.3 installed and i can't checkout, after complete all fields in the Billing Information section and press continue, i don't have any errors but appear something like this, and in the back of the image I see that State/Province is not select now, take a look at the image:

[image]

Comment: Is it a clean installation? Or did you do some cusumization or installed extensions?

Comment: i move the store, and is not any extension there. and when i move the store i thhink that I move all files :) i overwrite again the frontend/base folder skin/base folder. But is the same

Comment: Yes This happen with me don't worry i solved this You need to Comment some line of code in mage file. I just leave my office so I'll tell you tomorrow please comment below so I'll remember.

Comment: Hi is there any way to tell me what lines you modify?

Comment: Hi Anup Chaudhary please don't forgot to tell me what files we need to touch, to solve this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This is frequent issue with Magento 1.9.2.3 I don't know why? Try this. Go to `code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php` find `validate()` method in this method find

`$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();`

Replace it with

`$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();`

Simple.. Also, If you have not overridden Customer Model then do it. else make change directly in the Mage files.

Here are some link on this issue-

1.http://www.appseconnect.com/magento/magento-1-9-bug-getting-error-please-make-sure-your-password-while-customer-registration-checkout/

2.http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/fix-please-make-sure-password-match-issue-magento-1-9-1-0/

3.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311240/magento1-9-1-please-make-sure-your-password-match-issue

Try this and let me know once again, if work mark ans as read

Comment: Hi Anup,

thank you for your answer. In the code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php file I have start with line  844 <pre><code>        $confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
        if ($password != $confirmation) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
        }

so the modification is there, so no success

Comment: please take a look here this is the problem, i put there a  lot of informations about this error: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101750/magento-cant-pass-the-billing-step-in-the-checkout-page

Comment: My opinion is that exist two fields, maybe this fields can't saved in database, but i don't have any idea how to check this.

Comment: Hey, try to search with "**field is required fields" see where it is coming from. Also, add your code of validate function(). Please let me know are you using custom theme? You have any other Model of Customer in your local code?

Comment: Problem Solved- See this link- http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101750/magento-cant-pass-the-billing-step-in-the-checkout-page   Thanks To Robertd.