# Magento can't pass the Billing step in the checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, database, onepage-checkout, javascript, ajax

I have Magento 1.9.2.3 installed and I can't checkout, after complete all fields in the Billing Information section and press Continue, I have this error like in the attached image and when I check with Firebug i see this error.

```
http://example.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/

JSON
    error       1
    message     [""" is a required value.", """ is a required value."]
    0       """ is a required value."
    1       """ is a required value."
```

Firebug error:

[image]

This is the message after press Continue button example:

[image]

Update:

I try almost all solutions: 
1. app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
adding the id “checkout-payment-method-load” to fieldset so change line 36 from fieldset to fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load"
Anyone? any idea? 
2. I remove all fields from billing and I leave only first name and last name, the same error.

I think that is something from my database, I move the database to another host and in a new magento installation, i have the same error in the checkout process.

Update2: 
I found the this issue, is in My account too, I try to edit the New Address in My Account > Address Book and i have the same problem, and i observ when i try to save the State/Province field is deselect. I attach image here:

[image]

UPDATE:

I inspect the code again and I found that this message **"" is a required value.** come from here": /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Text.php. I try to remove almost all fields that are in the checkout billing page: I remove the code and I set to 0 in the eav_attributes, now there I have only First Name, Last Name, Country and State/Province. But the same error.

I observe when after press the continue button and the message appear that State/Province selection is automatically canceled. If you look in this picture is not selected now.
[image]
Anyone? Any ideas? 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this error does have its origin in some eav attribute validation in the saveBillingAction like here: https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1264aee821b451b3c88e55659cd1ee79d3b324af/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php#L284

I'm not 100% sure if this error comes from this, but you could check the eav_attribute table.

The customer should have the eav_entity_type id 1 (at least for me) and the custoemr address should have 2. (you can also look them up in the eav_entity_type table).

In the eav attribute table, theres a column 'is_required'. Although, its weird, that the attribute is empty in the message, you might find an attribute here, that is required (and then validated) in the table but not filled in in your checkout process.

It might also be a cache issue. If I'm recognizing corretly, there is a nasty cache for the eav attributes that could actually be responsible for such behaviour (given you changed or maybe deleted a customer or address attribute recently)

Comment: Hi Davin thank very much for your answer, I edit my post and I attach there my eav_attributes, where I will shoiuld look :) i'm not see anything there, may be you can?

Comment: can't find anything there on first sight. Actually it was an index and not a cache for the eav attributes. Did you try to make a full reindex yet?

Comment: yes, i reindex all and is the same.

Comment: Hi David I solve the problem, thank you so much, the bug was in the files structure. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: ok. very happy I could help :) could you maybe describe what basically went wrong? then I can update the answer for others who may have the same problem :)

Comment: i edit a lot of here and I don't know :) right :) maybe when I will have more time, I will post here, is ok? :)

Comment: Ok You solved you problem, Happy Coding...